# How to better organize two functions where function2 uses the result of function1?

Tags: optimization, c#-3.0

There is two functions with math calculations. They count two different values that could be used separately from each other. But function2 uses function1 value. Now I have sonething like this:

```
public double Function1()
{
/*...*/
return value1;
}
public double Function2()
{
double someValue = Function1();
/*...*/
return value2;
}
```

And if user needs to get value1 and after it value2 there will be repeatable array of code. Is this must be fixed? There can be situation when user needs only value2 so I don't know what to do with this reuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine the way you did it but if you really want to change it, assuming value1 and value 2 are not living only inside the functions, you cad do something like this:

```
private bool function1Called = false;
public double Function1()
{
    /*...*/
    function1Called = true;
    return value1;
}
public double Function2()
{
    double someValue;
    if (!funcion1Called)
    {
        someValue = Function1();
    {
    else
    {
        someValue = value1;
    }
    /*...*/
    return value2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Function2 depends on Function1 then this is fine.